# Using the method of induction

Tags: proof-writing

Can someone help solve this problem?

Prove that if $n≥1$ and $a_1,a_2,….,a_n$ are any real numbers, then $|a_1+a_2+⋯+a_n |≤|a_1 |+|a_2 |+⋯+|a_n |$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual induction approach, but you need something special at $n=2$.  It is clearly true for $n=1$.  Now prove $n=2$ from the triangle inequality.  Then if it is true for $k$ numbers, prove it is true for $k+1$ numbers by grouping the first $k$ into one group and combine them with the last one using your proof of $n=2$

Answer (score 1):

The base case is trivial. Now suppose we have already proven the assertion for $n\ge 1$. So $|\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i|=|a_{n+1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i|\le |a_{n+1}|+|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i|\le|a_{n+1}|+\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}|a_i|$, which closed the induction.

(Note that we use our inductive hypothesis $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i|\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_i|$  above)

So you only need to show that $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$